# Unknown Windows SID Mapped to Proxy During SSIS Package Execution

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory

I'm running SSIS packages stored in a SQL Server 2014 catalog via scheduled SSA jobs. I'm reviewing my SQL Audit capture and noting calls to SSISDB are coming from the proxy I created when looking at the value for `[session_server_principal_name],` but the SID showing up in `[server_principal_name]` doesn't correspond to the Active Directory SID. My proxy has an AD SID prefixed with the typical 'S-1-5...' but the audit is returning a SID with a prefix of 'S-1-9...'. Is that indicative of a contained user for SSISDB dynamically created at job runtime to execute the SSIS task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [blog post](http://www.sqlserverscience.com/tools/identify-login-sys-dm_exec_sessions-displayed-as-sid-s-1-9-3/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=dba.se.post&utm_campaign=135076) I wrote concerning how to identify this `S-1-9` SID.

From that post:

> This can happen as a result of using `EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';` to switch context to another user that **doesn’t have a server-level account**.

I imagine you'd see this exact scenario for contained users.

There is also an [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2006/07/03/quick-guide-to-db-users-without-logins-in-sql-server-2005/) post from 2006 showing this SID.